# Powershell Cannot find Get-SPWeb

Tags: powershell

I am using SP2013 onpremises. I'm using an account which is a Farm administrator and a Shell Administrator and a local admin on the SP Server.

I am running a Set-SPUser command and receiving the 'Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url: ". The URL is correct. I'm able to navigate to it with the account I'm executing the command with.

Set-SPUser -Identity $User -Web $spsite -email $email -SyncFromAD

where:
$User contains the domain\username (no claims identifier)

$spsite contains the FQDN to the site with no trailing slash or spaces.

$email is the users's properly formatted email address.

I should not that this is happening with a specific URL. I'm able to get the spweb to a site that was setup earlier. We use host named site collections on our farm.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my account had not been given membership to many of the newly created sites. I added the account to the sites and set the shell admin for that user on the DB I was working with and was able to get the spweb object.